# PHP SimpleXML and escaped strings

Tags: php, simplexml

I have a script pulls some data out of a database and then sends it in xml format using SimpleXML.  Clients that use the service load the xml using file_get_contents(*url-to-script*) and then use SimpleXML to find the relevant data and display it on a webpage.

The problem I am having is that the output on the webpage is always escaped.  It doesn't matter how many times I run the strings I am getting back through stripslashes, it is still escaped.

Any ideas how to strip the slashes?

EDIT:

The data is put into the database through a 3rd party application, we never enter it programmatically.  However, we extract from it in a number of other applications and it is not escaped.

We are not using addslashes on the data anywhere.

magic_quotes_gpc is on, all the other magic_quotes options are off

Comment: How about an example data of what the xml comes out as, so we can see it escaped?  How about post the snippet of code where the xml is retrieved from the database?

Answer (score 0):

Please try and answer the below questions and update your question, it will help figure out where your problem is

- How is the data being input into the database?
- Are you using [addslashes](http://www.php.net/addslashes) on it?
- Is [magic_quotes](http://www.php.net/magic_quotes) turned on on your server?
- Do you have an example of the xml data Before entry into the database and when it comes out?
- Can you post some of your code of where the xml data is entered into the database?

This is necessary information to help you without blindly guessing.